# How to style background color of active radio button in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have radio buttons which is to be styled when active. In my project, the buttons change background color only when selected and turns normal immediately. My intention is to change it like the one seen in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/urbandrone/y49df8wv/1/, but its in pure Javascript, how would it be done in React?

Following is the code reference

```
{newDate.map((data, i) => (
          <ButtonGroup toggle style={{ width: "100%" }}>
            <GridListTile style={gridListStylePhoto}>
              <h5>{currday(data.getDay())}</h5>
              <ToggleButton
                className="toggleButtonNew"
                key={i}
                type="radio"
                active="true"
                variant="light"
                name="radio"
                value={currday(data.getDay()) + " " + data.getDate()}
                checked={radioValue === data.getDate()}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  handleChange(e);
                }}
              >
                <br />
                {data.getDate()}
              </ToggleButton>
            </GridListTile>
          </ButtonGroup>
        ))}
```

Below is the CSS reference

```
input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
.btn-light {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: transparent;
}

{/* This is what I have  tried but of no use */}

.btn-light:checked {
  background-color: red;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  background-color: red;
}
```

How to change radio buttons background color when active and keep it even when clicked outside that button.

Following is the codesanbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-hcbxl

Comment: Please improve your original question instead of reposing it

Comment: Ya but, I have asked now bit differently and also included an example